# Using an Enterprise Wireless Access Point at Home

Tags: home-networking, wireless-access-point

I want to upgrade/extend my home wifi and found some used Aerohive AP370's, which  i believe are controllerless/cloud controlled (i.e pay subscription) Wireless AP's. I dont want to buy the subscription, would i be able to program them using the console port or via putty? It seems it would be possible to manage after subscription term ended according to this youtube video (15:30ish https://youtu.be/sRievDktfrA) But would like to know if I could set them up without a subscription.
Thanks in advance, Simba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That model appears to be out of support and subscriptions are $200 to $500 annually.   Since these are connected to the Internet, subscriptions are easy to monitor.

So I suggest you let these pass by and get a consumer Mesh system (Ubiquiti, Netgear) which can be used free of subscription once purchased and installed.

Support (often needed) for the simpler consumer gear is easier to get for a homeowner.

They may appear to be free (obtained used) but when factoring in subscription and the need for support, they are more expensive than consumer models.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, the main reason i am considering these access points over consumer ones is the price, namely 60$ per unit. Could i install openWRT or another program on it?

Comment: It looks like proprietary OEM gear so I would say probably not.

Comment: OK, so do you think they wont work at all without subscription? my understanding was that the subscription was for the online monitoring, as they use "cooperative control" to manage themselves (https://www.aerohiveworks.com/datasheets/Aerohive-Datasheet-AP370_new.pdf

Comment: I am fairly sure they will not work without a subscription. The vendor is likely to simple disable them.

Comment: Vendor as in aerohive? Accoding to youtube link, they still function after subscription expires, although the web based service is not availiable and so they need to be managed via their static IP/console port. That would seem to point to them not being disabled. However, if I dont ever connect to web service, should i be able configure it via a console cable?

Comment: Yes vendor as in aerohive.  Also it was sold to Extreme Networks, so that is the organization to deal with.  If you will never use them on the internet (seems strange for wireless devices) you can try the link you pointed to.